# How to set on a json a DateTime value with a specific format

Tags: java, json, junit, mockito

I'm setting values on a json that i want to send, but the value DateTime("2019-07-01T03:18:46Z") is not set on the json as i wanted to

I have tried to use the SimpleDateFormat, also with the DateTimeFormatter of the library joda but no one give me the result as a simple DateTime

```
EventDTO eventDTO = new EventDTO();
        eventDTO
                .withDescription("Description")
                .withIssueType("Notificación CNS")
                .withPriority("Medium")
                .withProjectKey("10000")
                .withIssueSubType("Apoderamiento de aeronave")
                .withSummary("Summary")
                .withRegion("LECM")
                .withAirport("LEBB")
                .withRaised(new DateTime("2019-07-01T03:18:46Z"));

        when(jiraService.create(eventDTO)).thenReturn(successResponseDTO);

        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(eventDTO);
```

the actual result that I'm getting is :

```
{"monthOfYear":7,"minuteOfHour":18,"hourOfDay":5,"yearOfEra":2019,"weekyear":2019,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfCentury":19,"millisOfDay":19126000,"secondOfDay":19126,"minuteOfDay":318,"era":1,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":1,"dayOfYear":182,"year":2019,"secondOfMinute":46,"millisOfSecond":0,"weekOfWeekyear":27,"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Europe/Paris"},"id":"Europe/Paris"},"millis":1561951126000,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Europe/Paris"},"id":"Europe/Paris"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false}
```

I expect to get just

```
2019-07-01T05:18:46.000+02:00
```

Comment: I don't think that is a duplicate, it doesn't work the solution that this post gives

Comment: The solution in the mentioned post does work, maybe you just did not apply it correctly. You might want to add what you tried to your question. -- Also the tags `junit` and `mockito` seem to be unrelated to what you are doing here.